# How do I confirm that my Mac has hibernated?

Tags: sleep-wake, macos, logs, hibernate

I believe I've correctly configured my MacBook Pro to hibernate (after a delay) when I close the lid, with the following [settings](https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-hibernate-a-mac--cms-23235)

```
 standbydelay         900
 standby              1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 powernap             0
 disksleep            0
 sleep                1
 autopoweroffdelay    28800
 hibernatemode        25
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        0
 displaysleep         2
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

However I'm not sure that my machine is actually hibernating as expected and would like to be able to confirm that it has.

Is there a way to do this?

I've tried things like

```
pmset -g log|grep -e " Sleep  " -e " Wake  "  -e " DarkWake " | tail -n 5
```

which gives, for example

```
2016-11-17 08:39:03 -0500 Wake                  Wake from Standby [CDNVA] due to EC.LidOpen/Lid Open: Using BATT (Charge:93%) 1630 secs 
2016-11-17 09:06:13 -0500 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep': Using Batt (Charge:83%) 868 secs  
2016-11-17 09:20:41 -0500 Wake                  Wake from Standby [CDNVA] due to EC.PME/User: Using BATT (Charge:83%) 462 secs  
2016-11-17 09:28:23 -0500 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Clamshell Sleep': Using Batt (Charge:80%) 4586 secs 
2016-11-17 10:44:49 -0500 Wake                  Wake from Standby [CDNVA] due to EC.LidOpen/Lid Open: Using BATT (Charge:79%)
```

and

```
pmset -g log | grep LidOpen | tail -n 5
```

which gives

```
2016-11-16 18:10:07 -0500 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] due to EC.LidOpen/Lid Open: Using AC (Charge:35%) 95 secs   
2016-11-16 18:27:04 -0500 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] due to EC.LidOpen/Lid Open: Using AC (Charge:53%) 675 secs  
2016-11-17 07:50:59 -0500 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] due to EC.LidOpen/Lid Open: Using AC (Charge:100%) 174 secs  
2016-11-17 08:39:03 -0500 Wake                  Wake from Standby [CDNVA] due to EC.LidOpen/Lid Open: Using BATT (Charge:93%) 1630 secs 
2016-11-17 10:44:49 -0500 Wake                  Wake from Standby [CDNVA] due to EC.LidOpen/Lid Open: Using BATT (Charge:79%)
```

or

```
pmset -g log | grep sleep | tail -n 5
```

which gives

```
2016-11-17 09:28:10 -0500 Assertions            PID 198(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context2626.preventuseridlesleep" 00:01:46  id:0x0x1000087fe [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2016-11-17 10:44:24 -0500 Assertions            Kernel Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler          
2016-11-17 10:54:12 -0500 Assertions            PID 198(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context2629.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:09:04  id:0x0x500008862 [System: DeclUser kDisp]          
2016-11-17 10:54:12 -0500 Assertions            PID 198(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context2629.preventuseridlesleep" 00:09:04  id:0x0x100008861 [System: DeclUser kDisp]          
Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
```

but I'm not sure any of these are the right commands, or how to interpret their results.

How do I confirm (ideally from the command line) that my Mac has hibernated?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to check:

```
pmset -g log | grep -i "wake from"
```

If the latest entry says: "Wake from Hibernate", the Mac was hibernated when you last woke it up (for example opened the lid).

If it says for example "Wake from Standby" it was not hibernated.

Comment: Is the omission of `tail` important? How is this different from what I tried in the OP?

Comment: No, it is not important. The tail part of your old command meant that you only saw the last 5 lines of the log file. This is different because I have explained for you exactly what to look for, which you didn't have in your question.